# run batch file in java program

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

There is batch file that contains a jar file.
I want to run a batch file in a java program in netbeans.
I used this code:

```
Process p=    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c  start  \"C:\\Users\\123\\Desktop\\New folder (6)\\Browser.bat\"");
```

But by running this code, a cmd windows in open and below address is shown and batch file doesn't run.

```
C:\Users\123\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication19
```

That is different from the address of batch file.

batch file contains:

```
java -jar -Xms32m -Xmx512m Browser.jar
```

using ProcessBuilder:
the jar file runs.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java.exe", "-jar","-Xms32m", "-Xmx512m", "C:\\Users\\123\\Desktop\\New folder (6)\\Browser.jar");
  pb.directory(new File("C:\\Windows\\System32"));
  Process p = pb.start();
```

using ProcessBuilder for batch file:
program runs successfully but jar file not execute.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java.exe", "-jar","-Xms32m", "-Xmx512m", "C:\\Users\\Saeedeh\\Desktop\\New folder (6)\\FarsNetBrowser.jar");
pb.directory(new File("C:\\Windows\\System32"));
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: What is printed seems just the cmd prompt advertising the current directory

Comment: use a process builder and set the initial path of the process to the folder where the batch file is at. Does the batch file work from command prompt directly?

Comment: yes, it is printed the current directory of netbeans.

Comment: search google for process builder. change the current folder of the Process Builder to the folder where the batch file is 'C:\\Users\\123\\Desktop\\New folder (6)\' in your case. read up the process builder javadoc

Comment: @tgkprog I added a code with ProcessBuilder. it runs the jar file.

Comment: Running a cmd script or any arbitrary program are two different things. If you are still interested in the former, try to remove the "start" argument from your command line as I suggested in my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \"C:/Users/123/Desktop/New folder (6)/Browser.bat\"");
```

Comment: The slashes are the difference. / is not the same as \.

Comment: ok, but I think the path is correct. I tryed with your code but the result is same.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's an extra `start` in your command line. It should work by just using

```
cmd /c "C:\Users\123\Desktop\New folder (6)\Browser.bat"
```

and I would let Java escape argument instead of hardcoding the string:

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", PATH_OF_THE_BAT_FILE);
```

Comment: thanks. I used first line in my code but unable to access jar file browser.jar  , and by second code the java program runs successfully but jar file dose not runs.

Comment: That's just because you use relative pathnames but don't set the right working directory for the child process